# Second level url not working with PrivateRoute

Tags: reactjs, laravel, react-router

By following some tutorial I am finally able to create an authentication system using React js.
When I access the `path` prop of `PrivateRoute` component, this path first checks the authenticity of user then redirect the user to requested path if authenticated successfully.

Now the problem is when I use first level url like `127.0.0.1/dashboard` path on `PrivateRoute` prop, it works fine and redirect me to dashboard and I can see that in browser's console the `PrivateRoute` component is being called.

But when I use second level url like `127.0.0.1/admin/dashboard` path on `PrivateRoute` prop, the component was not even called (nothing in browser's console) and I was redirected to login page.

I don't understand what causes this redirection and how can I make authentication system work for second level url just like first level url.

Here is my code

**MainComponent.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {AuthContext} from '../auth/AuthContext';

import {Route, Switch} from "react-router-dom";
import Login from "../auth/Login";
import Dashboard from "../dashboard/Dashboard";
import {PrivateRoute} from "../route/PrivateRoute";
import {PublicRoute} from "../route/PublicRoute";

const MainComponent = (props) => {

    return (
        <div id="wrapper" className="menu-displayed">

             <Switch>
                   <PublicRoute exact path="/" component={Login}/>
                   <PrivateRoute exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard}/>
                   <PrivateRoute exact path="/admin/dashboard" component={Dashboard}/>
             </Switch>

        </div>
    );
};
export default MainComponent
```

**PrivateRoute.js**

```
import React, {useContext} from "react";
import {Route, Redirect} from "react-router-dom";
import {AuthContext} from "../auth/AuthContext";

export const PrivateRoute = ({
         component: Component,
         ...rest
     }) => {

    const {isAuthenticated} = useContext(AuthContext);

    console.log(`Private: ${isAuthenticated}`);

    return (
        <Route {...rest} component={(props) => (
            isAuthenticated ? (
                <Component {...props} />
            ) : (
                <Redirect to="/" />
            )
        )}/>
    )
}
```

**AuthContext.js**

```
import React, {createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState} from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import cookie from "react-cookies";

export const AuthContext = createContext();

const AuthContextProvider = (props) => {

    const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        cookie.load('token') ? setIsAuthenticated(true) : setIsAuthenticated(false);
    });

    function login(email, password) {

        axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/login', {
            email: email,
            password: password
        },
            {
                headers: {"Authorization": `Bearer ${cookie.load('token')}`}
            })
            .then(function (response) {

                cookie.save('token', response.data.token, {path:'/'});
                setIsAuthenticated(true);

            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });

    }

    function logout() {
        cookie.remove('token');
        setIsAuthenticated(false);
    }

    const checkAuthenticated = () => {
        if (cookie.load('token'))
        {
            setIsAuthenticated(true);
        }
    }

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{isAuthenticated, login, logout}}>
            {props.children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )

}

export default AuthContextProvider;
```

***Note:***
*I am using React js with Laravel and redirecting all path to single view using below Route*

```
Route::view('/{path?}', 'layouts.main');
```

Comment: Not that I think *this* is the cause of your issue, but a slightly simpler private route logic is to simply return `return isAuthenticated ? <Route {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/" />;` Returning anything *other* than a `Route` or `Redirect` within a `Switch` can have undesirable affects.

Comment: so you mean I shouldn't have `PrivateRoute` within a `Switch`?

Comment: No, sorry for confusion, that is ok, since it returns a `Route` (which subsequently renders a component or `Redirect`). I misspoke a little, what you have is ok since the `PrivateRoute` ***is*** returning a `Route` for the `Switch.